# MVP: Don't keep activities.Is presenter alive?

Tags: android, mvp

In my phone when minimize aplicatoin then the Android always destroy activity. In Developer options I turn "Don't keep activities"

I use MVP.
When I minimize application the activity is ALWAYS destroy. Call method onDestroy().

OK.

But the question is: Is with activity also ALWAYS destroy presenter and model?

Comment: Of course the activity is destroyed when you enable "Don't keep activities"

Comment: But presenter and model are destroy?

Comment: Every instance in the activity is destroyed when the activity is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When your activity is destroyed, all the objects in that activity will also be destroyed.

You can recover the state of some objects by saving them into a Bundle before the activity gets destroyed and then retrieving them from the Bundle once the Activity is recreated.

Please, take a look at the documentation for the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).